# Emacs23 and pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, emacs

I use emacs23 in my laptop (Ubuntu). I would like to obtain a PDF file with pdflatex. But I don't know how to do. I am a beginner in using emacs23.

Comment: You might want to consider using AucTeX - an emacs library for TeX/LaTeX files.  You can find the manual online: http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/index.html

Answer (score 4):

If you use AUCTeX set the variable `TeX-PDF-mode` to true. To set this permanently add the following

```lisp
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

to your ~/.emacs

When the variable is set to true `C-c C-c` will produce a pdf (rather than a dvi).

To set `TeX-PDF-mode` to true for the current session hit `C-c C-t C-p`.

Reference: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX#toc5

AUCTeX is packaged for Ubuntu. To install it do `apt-get install auctex`.

Comment: Note that if you want set the `TeX-Pdf-mode` to true for the current session, just hit `C-c C-t C-p`.

Comment: @Quinn Cheers, I've update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Asking such questions is not a promising approach to learn how to use Emacs. You need to read a manual or at least a tutorial about Emacs -- there are many on the web, probably in your language -- and as well about the Emacs extension AUCTeX. Emacs is much more difficult to use than e.g. Kile, but after you've spent some days on learning how to use it, you'll be better off.

I do not recommend to start learning LaTeX *and* Emacs at the same time.

---

EDIT: [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey) convinced me to add links for readers who take a start with Emacs and AUCTeX in English.

The Tutorial provided by Emacs is excellent, Emacs asks you to do it when started for the first time. However, here is a link: http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/tour/

As a second step, install and learn how to use AUCTeX, see here: http://www.gnu.org/s/auctex/manual/auctex.html

And no, there is no easy way to learn it. You have to invest some time. But even me -- a busy lawyer in Germany in the forties -- managed to comprehend it. Hey, Emacs + AUCTeX and LaTeX is stable and reliable.

Comment: -1, unfriendly: The whole Emacs manual is vast, and a beginner should not be expected to read it, only one of the tutorials.  Learning by doing is good, and the bundled documentation for Auctex is not the easiest to navigate when configuring.

Comment: I have just started to learn Emacs and I think that an RTFM attitude is bad in that it might scare of users (my opinion is that Emacs and its community is more inaccessible than it needs to be!). Rather we should be welcoming if we want people to use Emacs. I think the best way to learn Emacs is to mix these things: reading manuals, working in Emacs, asking questions and looking other people's setup.

Comment: What would be best is if there were a good tutorial to using LaTeX with Emacs.  I would say that Emacs is a complicated system and mysterious, and completely agree with the last sentence of this post!  Whilst I don't like RTFM answers, I do think that RTM is appropriate and RTT even better.  "Where do I begin" is a very hard question to answer and that's what tutorials and manuals are designed for.  What this answer is really missing is a direct link to such a tutorial, but that's all that I would say it is missing.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I do not know the mother tongue of Rasolof, but I have doubts it is English. If it were English or German, I had recommended something, e.g. (German) some remarks on my own regarding Emacs: http://www.komascript.de/node/1471

Comment: Keks: It's worth editing that into the main post.  Even if Rasolof can't read it, others finding this question may be able to do so and it's easier to find in the main text of your answer than buried here in the comments.

Comment: I've un-minus-oned this, per the edits.